# Unable to Install Pandas-profiling

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, pandas-profiling

I am trying to install **Pandas-Profiling** package for Jupyter Notebook but no luck!!!

Tried installing the package from the **Anaconda Navigator (Home) -> Environment -> base(root) -> Search packages -> Pandas-profiling**

A dialog box appears to show as `"Solving Package modifications"` but after some time, the dialog box appears blank!!!

[image]

Tried `"Conda prompt"` option also but it shows deprecated

Comment: have you tried pip install. I didnt get any issue when I installed, infact I did it from my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Try installing it from Anaconda Prompt `conda install pandas-profiling`. I strongly caution against following advice to use `pip`, especially as this appears to be your **base** env. Why that's a bad idea is detailed in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's a version issue.
Try this

```
!pip install -U pandas-profiling
```

[Reference](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/183)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Good luck!

[Reference](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/183)